# How to sort a list of 1billion elements in python

Tags: python, sorting

How to sort a list of 1 billion elements in python
Please elaborate
Assuming we have unlimited space.

Thanks for the answers, but, this question is asked in the perspective of optimizing algorithm to sort, not to work on python. This question is asked in an interview, in the context of, having large number of elements, may be integers or strings, this probably wont be used in real world as we have techniques like pagination.

Comment: This question doesn't have enough details about what your constraints are, what you're trying to do and such to provide a cogent answer. Assuming we have a LOT of memory, you could just call `sorted` on the dictionary to sort its keys.

Comment: Add some details please

Comment: You use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) because it works and it is fast. Do you need more?

Comment: If we have infinite space then we must also have infinite time, so we could sort the keys using paper and pencil. Voila!

Comment: Please provide more detail, like what you tried so far /

Comment: please add some more details - what is the goal , conditions, system requirements etc, basically it is a good question and i'm interested so hear the answers

Comment: @user8463813 Did my answer solve your problem? In this case, I would be happy, if you could mark it as the correct answer for future users. Otherwise, please ask your further questions in the comments section of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are unordered. They are hash tables and you are not guaranteed the order of keys in a hash table.

If you require the keys to be ordered, try the ordered dict class in collections.

If you need to sort the keys you could place them in a list, and sort the list.

```
my_dict = {key: value for key, value in zip(keys, values)} # Example dict
keys = [i for i in my_dict]
keys.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary on its own does not store a key order. For this, you will have to use the [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) which stores the order of insertion.

If you just need to iterate through the sorted keys, you can use `sorted`:

```
for key in sorted(my_dict):
    # output is already sorted by dictionary key
    print key, my_dict[key]
```

if you need to specify a special key or method, you could pass this as information to sorted. The following example sorts by value:

```
for key, value in sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    # output is sorted by value
    print key, value
```

Sort orders can be reversed by using `reversed`:

```
for key in reversed(sorted(my_dict)):
    # output is already sorted descending by dictionary key
    print key, my_dict[key]
```

Finally, this code snippet would fill an OrderedDict with sorted key/value pairs:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
my_ordered_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

#### Since you updated your question from dictionary to list

Sorting lists is even easier, just use `sorted` (again, provide a small method, if you have a different sorting key):

```
sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list)
```